# Turn Implementation for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, turn

I am new to the Peer to Peer communication and Currently I work on Peer to Peer communication project. So I need an TURN library for proceed my work. I search through the internet for the TURN implementation on python but couldn't get a useful result.

Is there any python implementation of TURN library (For clients).

Comment: Using Python and C: https://github.com/node/turn-client

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.